# Pixel is added to inline font-weight

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In javascript I'm defining some in-line stylings, one of them is font-weight. Unfortunately it doesn't work as automatically 'px' is added at the end of the value and then it doesn't get rendered as the value is not correct :

Note: I'm using react , therefore the code looks like the following.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {
                        data.map(function(d, i) {
                            var style = {};
                            if (d.value === 'selected') {
                                style['color'] = '#FFFFFF';
                                style['font-size'] = '16px';
                                style['font-style'] = 'normal';
                                style['font-weight'] = '700';
                                style['text-transform'] = 'uppercase';
                            }else {
                                style['border'] = '2px solid #C9C9C9';
                                style['color'] = '#C9C9C9';
                                style['font-size'] = '12px';
                                style['font-style'] = 'normal';
                                style['font-weight'] = '400';
                            }
                            return (<td>
                                <div style={style}>
                                    {d.value}
                                </div>
                            </td>);
                        })
                        }
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

When I inspect it in chrome, it shows : `font-weight: 700px` and it doesn't work as `px` makes the value incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `style['fontWeight']` instead of `style['font-weight']` according to the react documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/style-props-value-px.html) the fontWeight property will not get the automatic 'px' suffix.